# How to connect to local MySql database using PHP.

Tags: php, mysql

we are trying to connect to our local mysql database using PHP. We left out the password on purpose but is it correct. However, this is not working, we keep getting following error message: Warning: mysqli_connect() expects parameter 5 to be long, string given in.

It is referring to line 7 which would be `$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $port, $uname, $pword, $dbname);`

```
<?php
$servername = "Mysql@127.0.0.1";
$port = "3306";
$uname = "root@localhost";
$pword = "1234";
$dbname = "database";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $port, $uname, $pword, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
?>
```

Our confiq.php file

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'database');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root@localhost');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'Mysql@127.0.0.1');

define('port', '3306');


/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Comment: Read the documentation and pay attention to the order of the parameters: http://www.php.net/mysqli_connect

Answer (score 1):

You have the args in the wrong order in the constructor

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $port, $uname, $pword, $dbname);
 should be 
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $uname, $pword, $dbname, $port );
```

It looks however like the info in the config file is incorrect -

```
define('DB_HOST', 'Mysql@127.0.0.1');
```

would, I suspect, actually be

```
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
```

though perhaps not!

so then, using the info from your config file, the connection would be:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, port );
```

Comment: Thanks, i have tried this but now i get this error message instead: Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host 'Mysql@127.0.0.1' (1)

Comment: see above edited code - I thought it looked `iffy` ~ try just `127.0.0.1` which is the standard for localhost

Comment: Thanks I tried removing MySql@127.0.0.1 and replacing it with 127.0.0.1 however this only created a new problem. I got this error msg: Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)

Comment: is the db server the same machine upon which you are coding? Find the ip / hostname of the mysql server and use that in the config

Comment: Yes it is and the host is the same in our connection file

Comment: https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-fix-error-establishing-a-database-connection-in-wordpress might be of help.